# How to disable sp_send_dbmail usage in Store Procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have taken over a poorly written system and executing a particular Store Procedure it seems to be invoking `sp_send_dbmail`. Currently I do not even see in the store procedure it self where `sp_send_dbmail` is even been called.  At this stage i'm looking for a way to have permanently disabled it from the store procedures and where its even been called from. Perhaps its only called when a store procedures errors out? if so where is that been set?

This is what my store procedure looks like:

```
USE [pis]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[deal_note]    Script Date: 4/15/2015 7:25:27 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[deal_note](
    @keycode        varchar(50),
    @deal_id        int,
    @notes          varchar(max)
) as
/*



    select * from dbo.consumernotes
*/
begin
    set nocount on
    --parse key and code
    declare @key            int
    declare @code           int
    select
        @key    = left(@keycode, charindex('-',@keycode)-1),
        @code   = substring( @keycode, charindex('-', @keycode)+1, len(@keycode) )

    declare @user_id        int

    select top 1
        @user_id        = k.[user_id]
    from acc.Keys k
    where k.id = @key
        and k.code = @code

    insert into dbo.ConsumerNotes 
        (deal_id, notes, created_by )
    select @deal_id, @notes, @user_id 

    if @@rowcount>0
        select '0' [code], 'note' [section], 'Record updated.' [message]
    else
        select '1' [code], 'note' [section], 'Error updating record..' [message]


end--procedure
```

Comment: Check 2 things: triggers for table dbo.ConsuemrNotes and place where the procedure is called (Line `select '1' [code], 'note' [section], 'Error updating record..' [message]` suggests that potential error is handel somewhere else)

Comment: I would also check on sql agent jobs, maybe they have set up some sort of custom error checking there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to temporarily stop your Database Mail, do this by adding the following statement at the start of the Procedure:

```
EXECUTE MSDB.dbo.sysmail_stop_sp
```

At the end of the procedure you will want to start the Database Mail again, which can be done with:

```
EXECUTE MSDB.dbo.sysmail_start_sp
```